# Scala Existential Types for Multi Parameter F-Bounded Polymorphic Types

Tags: scala, types, polymorphism, type-parameter, existential-type

I am using a library with a class that has a definition that looks like this:

```
abstract class ParentClass[X, Y <: ParentClass[X, Y, M], M <: OtherClass[X, M]]
```

This class has subclasses that extend this class like so:

```
abstract class ChildClass[B, C <: ChildClass[B, C, D], D <: OtherChildClass[B, D]] extends ParentClass[B, C, D]
```

And that subclass has subclasses that extend it in this manner:

```
class SomeClass extends ChildClass[F, SomeClass, SomeOtherClass]
```

How would I go about handling generics for `ParentClass`? For example, if I wanted to create an `Array` of objects that share the same ancestor type `ParentClass`, I could do this:

```
getArrayOfParentClass(): Array[ParentClass[_, _, _]]
```

But this doesn't respect the type bounds proposed in the class definition.
It seems like existential types are one of the main solutions for F-Bounded Polymorphic types, but I can't seem to figure out a solution using existential types that handles this case, nor have I seen any examples with regards to existential types with classes that have more than 1 type parameter.  I imagine it would work something like this, but haven't been able to quite figure it out:

```
// Doesn't compile
getArrayOfParentClass(): Array[X forSome {type X <: ParentClass[A, X, M forSome {type M <: OtherClass[A, M]}]
```

Answer (score 0):

The syntax you want is

```
Array[X forSome { type X <: ParentClass[A, X, M]; type M <: OtherClass[A, M] }]
```